# How to populate jquery DataTable using data in Web API calls

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, datatables

I'm a newbie about ASP.NET and jquery.
I want to populate the DataTable using ajax. with the data coming from a Web API.

e.g

```
api/Employees
```

Here's my code.

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    ajax: '/api/Employees',
    columns: [ ... ]
});
```

But I got an error message:

> DataTables warning: table id = myTable - Ajax error. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Do you know what the issue? because when I run the web api call `api/Employess` in the web browser the data displayed correctly in XML format.

Comment: Show the html for #myTable

Comment: XML format you say...? Can you output json instead because I'm pretty sure that's your issue: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/12879/xml-as-source-for-datatable

Comment: Please share your Web API code.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your API is returning a successful response. I'd need to see some code to be sure, but a wild guess would be that your API response must have the following structure for it to work nicely with dataTable:

```
{ "data": [{}, {}, {}, (..)] }
```

Answer (score 0):

pl check this link
https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "type": "POST"
  }
} );
```